# checking number of json arrays and generating series based on that number

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I'm receiving JSON data with the following function:

```
      function fecske4() {
       
          var url4 = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart/range?vs_currency=' + valuta + '&from=' + monthAgo + '&to=' + currentTime;
       fetch( url4 )
            .then(function (response) { return response.json(); })
            .then(function (data) { appendData4(data); });    setTimeout(fecske4, 20000); }; fecske4()
```

this works fine, but I'd like to simplify feeding the received data to a line chart. Currently its handwritten like this (in "series"):

```
   function appendData4(data) {       

               new Chartist.Line('#chart3', {
    
    series: [[ data.prices[0][1],data.prices[4][1],data.prices[9][1],data.prices[14][1],data.prices[19][1],data.prices[24][1],data.prices[29][1],data.prices[34][1],data.prices[39][1],data.prices[44][1],data.prices[49][1],data.prices[54][1],data.prices[59][1],data.prices[64][1],data.prices[69][1],data.prices[74][1],data.prices[79][1],data.prices[84][1],data.prices[89][1],data.prices[94][1],data.prices[99][1],data.prices[104][1],data.prices[109][1],data.prices[114][1],data.prices[119][1],data.prices[124][1]]]
             
             
  }, { fullWidth: true, 
       showPoint: false, 
       chartPadding: { top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 },
       lineSmooth: true, 
       axisX: { showGrid: false, showLabel: false, offset: 0, position: 'start', }, 
       axisY: { showGrid: false, showLabel: false, offset: 0, position: 'start', },  } );    
 }
```

which works, but has zero flexibility.

I'd like to check how many objects are in the json to get the exact number of data price points and generate the above shown "data.prices[0][1]" series automatically based on that number. How do I do that?

- additionally how do I get every 4th data point instead of all (fetching all takes longer to process and makes the line chart look crazy busy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the points to every fourth, you can use `filter`:

```js
let filteredPrices = data.prices.filter((item, index) => index % 4 == 0);
```

Then you can get the number of points just by `filteredPrices.length`.

Also, if you never need the first item of prices, you can map to a new array with just the second item:

```js
let chartData = data.prices.map((item) => item[1]);
```

You can combine the two actions - first filter, then map. Edited to show where to include this:

```js
function appendData4(data) {    
  let chartData = data.prices
    .filter((item, index) => index % 4 == 0)
    .map((item) => item[1]);
   
  new Chartist.Line('#chart3', {
    series: chartData
    ...
```

Makes sense to wrap this logic in a function of its own, like `prepareData` or something.

Comment: this looks quite promising, but in my example I don't really get any response - do I have to add .prices to it like: data.prices.filter or..? can you please put this in the above example snippet so I see how to structure it with a working example?

Comment: Sorry yeah, depends on how your data is structured, but sounds like you need `data.prices`, corrected the answer.

Comment: can you please add a snippet showing how I would use this mapped and the filtered data to replace the currently hand written data in the "series"? sorry I'm quite new to fetch and json

Comment: Edited my answer to make the example more complete

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out!

also,I actually need all prices, this: data.prices[0][1] is the first price as the price response looks like this: timestamp, price - so I don't need the data.prices[0][0] because that is the timestamps not the prices :) (so first number is cycling through the data second is switching between timestamp and price)

Comment: Yeah that is what the filter and map do - they process the entire array and return a new one.

Comment: works, thanks a lot! what was missing only is the square brackets around series, this is the perfect formula: series: [ chartData ]

Comment: Good to hear! Yeah I noticed that the data is wrapped in another array, but forgot to mention it.